# Keep other columns untouched

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to divide some columns by fixed number (`1000`) and remove commas, also change mix type into `int` with the second last code line. Except the list of `columns`, I do have other columns that are being deleted after executing the code. How can I keep other columns?

```
df_1 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(directory,'copy.xlsm'), sheet_name= "weekly",header= None)
df_1 = df_1.drop(df_1.columns[[0,1]], axis=1)

df_1.columns = df_1.loc[3].rename(None)
df_1 = df_1.drop(range(5))
columns =["A","B","D", "G"]
df_1=df_1.loc[:len(df_1) - 2, columns].replace(',', '', regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric) / 1000

df_1.to_csv(directory+'new.csv', index=False, header= True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this part:

```
df_1 = df_1.loc[...]...
```

You're overriding the original value of `df_1` to a subset of your columns (and it seems that you're losing some rows too) when using this selector: `[:len(df_1) - 2, columns]`. You only need to update the values of that selection:

```
df_1.loc[...] = df_1.loc[...]...
```

By using `loc` as the target value to store the result of your operation, you're only modifying those rows and columns with the values where they should be.

Your code should contain this line instead (added for clarity):

```
df_1.loc[:len(df_1) - 2, columns] = df_1.loc[:len(df_1) - 2, columns].replace(',', '', regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric) / 1000
```

Comment: if i remove `df_1=`  i have unchanged dataframe, nothing divide by 1000, nor removed commas

Comment: I didn't remove that part, I added a `.loc` after that: df_1.loc[...] = df_1.loc[...]...

Comment: I just noticed that it did not drop last two rows. Also last 4 row were not amended ( removed commas or divided by 1000). other rows had changed. what could be a reason?

Comment: When using the loc selector you're only retrieving those rows and updating those values. If you wan't to remove the last two rows of your selection you'll need to do that step afterwards. If it didn't work for some rows, I'm not sure what might be. Try using a simpler operation (like assign None) and double-check your selection